# No HTTPS redirect on image files

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've added the following to .htaccess to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

This is working ok for normal page requests. Just fyi, using **%{HTTPS} off** didn't work on our server and **!on** resulted in an infinite redirect loop. {HTTPS} is not defined when request is HTTP. Server port works. Domain check is included as switching just one site for now.

However, when requesting say an image file directly over HTTP (e.g. /images/myimage.jpg), it's not redirecting to HTTPS. Shouldn't the rules above apply to any request? If not, is there a different way of redirecting file requests?

Comment: The rules _do_ apply to all requests. Most likely you are looking at a cached result for those requests.

Comment: What you describe about the `%{HTTPS}` is strange, I have never seen such behavior and this clearly contradicts the official documentation.

Comment: Not cached; cleared browser cache and still fetched over HTTP instead of HTTPS. As for %{HTTPS} !on, yes somewhat bizarre. Seems a bug in mod_rewrite i.e. {HTTPS} only initialised on first pass and not when HTTP.

Comment: Also confirmed this behaviour with ScreamingFrog, which is what initially highlighted the lack of redirects for file requests.

Comment: Something is fishy in this. Some important details is missing. Two strange effects in one go make all warning lamps blink ;-)

Comment: Please add those rewriting rules into the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files. That is more efficient and robust anyway. Any change?

Comment: Can't do that. While this is a dedicated WHM/cPanel server, it's hosting multiple sites and we're phasing a switch to HTTPS. What important details are missing? There are further rules (this is a Magento multi-store setup), but none of the following rules do anything with protocol.

Comment: Ah, there are additional rules? So most likely those rules are applied and terminate the rewriting process _before_ those rules you posted were considered. You might want to enable rewrite logging to be able to understand the details.

Comment: My understanding is that the [L] flag should tell the rewrite engine to make the change and then pass the resulting URL back through the rules. Next pass it is then HTTPS so proceeds with the next set of rules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148049/discussion-between-adam-lavery-and-arkascha).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. Magento has an .htaccess file in the root of the media folder. This is where rewrite rules for certain image files were being sourced from and also needed to be changed to redirect to HTTPS.

Lesson: check down the folder tree for rewrite rules at deeper levels!